# Nuxtjs getting firestore data within asyncData

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to convert my VueJS app to NuxtJS to work with SSR. I'm stuck trying to get data loaded with asyncData. When I add my query to a `'mounted() {}'` function it works fine but I can't get it to work with `asyncData(){}` so that I can use SSR.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this.

My code:

```
 <ul>
   <li v-for='province in provinces' v-bind:key="province.id"> {{province.name_nl}}</li>
      </ul>

  asyncData () {
    return { msg: 'Welcome to my  new app' }
    const moment = require("moment");
    var date = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    let housesArray = []
    let provincesArray = []

    return firebase.firestore()
      .collection('provinces')
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        provincesArray.push(doc.data());
        });
        return {provinces: provincesArray}
      });
  },
```

Or is there another way I should be doing this? Keeping in mind that it does have to work with SSR.

PS: Yes this code is inside my pages folder, not the component, I know that's not allowed.

Comment: so what errors? how its not working

Comment: Im not getting any errors, but i also cant console.log or debug the code. So it doesn’t show anything. So i’m not sure where to start.

Comment: you have a return at top of asyncData so no code past that executed

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that the code after a return doesn't get executed. Still trying to learn. But then I still can't return the firestore data because I need to execute 2 calls to firestore, but if I return both with return {provinces: provincesArray, houses: housesArray} the firestore function isn't always executed before the return, any idea on what I have to do to wait for the response, or some documentation anyone knows of that could point me in the correct direction?

Comment: I just needed to add 'async' 'await' to fix it, thanks for the help.

Comment: @jonas could you post the updated answer below as your solution?  I have the same issue

Comment: @pmanning yes of course, sorry. Should have thought of that myself. :) Anyway I added my solution now. Just let me know if it isn't clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using `asyncDate()` you can add the `async` and `await` keywords to wait for the response(s) before returning them.

How I solved it:

```
 async asyncData () {
    const moment = require("moment");
    var date = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    let housesArray = []
    let provincesArray = []

await firebase.firestore()
  .collection('provinces')
  .orderBy('name_nl')
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      provincesArray.push(doc.data());
    });
  });

await firebase.firestore()
  .collection("houses")
  .where("valid_until", ">", date)
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      housesArray.push(doc.data());
    });
  });

return {
  provinces: provincesArray,
  houses: housesArray
}
  },
```

Comment: how do you import firebase/firestore in .vue?

Comment: Have a look at the tutorial here: https://medium.com/@anas.mammeri/vue-2-firebase-how-to-build-a-vue-app-with-firebase-authentication-system-in-15-minutes-fdce6f289c3c 

It's from a while back but I think everything is still relevant.